# Java recalling object issue

Tags: java, oop, object

I can't get my head around calling back an object that's been created. For example if we assume I have created 3 instances of, `Person` class. How can I retrieve back the first object's methods/details. I do not need any code, I simply need to know the theory on how to do this.

Thank You.

Comment: Huh?  You just call its methods (or access its variables).

Comment: Well you need to remember the reference somewhere - e.g. in a collection, a variable or whatever...

Comment: Oli, Yeah but I can only access last created object's methods/variables. When you create multiple objects, it becomes a problem. Like Jon said, I need to use the object reference to call 1 specific object from 100 objects.

Comment: You can access only the objects for which you have references. Once all references to a particular object are destroyed, the object is considered to be potential junk and can be claimed by garbage collector at any time. So if you create 100 Person objects, you can place their references in a collection, that way you prevent these objects from being destroyed, as long as the reference to your collection is not destroyed.

Comment: How long after this initial Person instance are you looking to recall it? If it's inside a block, then you need to assign it to a variable, if it's anywhere in a running JVM, then you can look into a Singleton, if it's between multiple executions of a program, then you need to look into serialization (possibly to a database).  If it's across a network then your options can include things like RMI, REST and any number of technologies.

Answer (score 1):

(Apologies for possibly weird syntax, I use Scala more than Java)

If you create your objects in this way:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
   Person p = new Person();
}
```

then your Person objects are lost once you go to the next iteration in cycle.

Even if you have Person object outside the cycle:

```
Person p;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
   p = new Person();
}
```

then every time you assign a new Person object to p, the previous one is lost, because there is no reference to it anywhere else.

But if you add the created objects to a collection, like this:

```
List<Person> plist = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person p;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
   p = new Person();
   plist.add(p);
}
```

then your Person objects (the references to them) are stored in `plist` and can be accessed as long as you keep `plist` in scope:

```
Person p0 = plist.get(0);
Person p1 = plist.get(1);
Person p2 = plist.get(2);
```

Comment: Can you confirm this for me. When I create multiple objects in a row, each object replaces the previous one. So really there is only one object and each object created replaces the previous object. Is that right? I hope it makes sense.